# Problem with writing in Hebrew in LyX

Tags: lyx, hebrew

I'm using LyX to write in Hebrew. I was using LyX 2.3.1 and wished to update it to the newest version, so I followed the [installation instructions from LyX wiki](https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew). About a month ago I've done the exact same thing on another computer and everything went smooth, but now it doesn't work and I'm frustrated and close to go back to pen and papers...

It looks like the language settings are not correct; first, somehow on my other computer it writes in LyX in Hebrew even though the computer language is English, but now I have to turn the computer languate to Hebrew. But the main problem is that I cannot compile any file, either in Hebrew or in English, and receive the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: File `cp1255.def' not
> found.

Please find below a minimal example file:

```
#LyX 2.3 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 544
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language hebrew
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_minted 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
כככ
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an mwe! I tried it on my computer and it compiles to PDF and the PDF looks good from what I can tell. I don't think I can help since I'm clueless on Windows. On Ubuntu I have that file thanks to the "babel-hebrew" package. Do you have that package installed?

Comment: You might want to try a different approach and use XeTeX and UTF8 for Hebrew documents. It will save you a lot of trouble down the road. You can use the file from https://github.com/guyru/lyx-hebrew-templates as a starting point. Just modify the fonts used in the document settings.